# MS SQL report error description

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

While runing MS SQL report I get an error "Error: Subreport could not be shown.".
Is there any way to get more information regarding an error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are [various SSRS log files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157403(SQL.90).aspx) generated on the server

It should be in one of these (can't recall exactly which one)